# Order xsl for loop as well as limting the loop to only five

Tags: xml, xslt

let's say I have this xml data. What I am needing to do is loop through this and give me the earliest 5. So newest to oldest and only output 5.

I am curently doing

```
<xsl:for-each select="TEST_DATA[not(position() >5)]">
    <xsl:sort select="DATE" order="descending"/>
        The rest of the mapping...

<TEST_DATA>
  <DATE>20160401</DATE>
  </TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20160501</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20160601</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20160301</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20150201</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20110301</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20160301</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
<TEST_DATA>
    <DATE>20160101</DATE>
</TEST_DATA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change that to

```
<xsl:for-each select="TEST_DATA">
    <xsl:sort select="DATE" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 5">...</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That is doing the same thing for me. Only giving me 5 but it is not sorting it.